# Openscoring returns results when required input field is missing

Tags: machine-learning, pmml, openscoring

I am using openscoring 1.2.13.

When querying a model with missing input fields, I still get results. This behaviour is inconsistent with JPMML classifier which returns an error message:

`Execute failed: The column XXX does not exist in the table`

1. Is openscoring expected not to return an error in such cases?
2. Can I make the openscoring server return the same response in such cases?

Comment: Openscoring 1.2.13 was released more than a year ago. The comparison with latest JPMML evaluator versions does not make much sense.

Comment: Using JPMML version 1.1.3v201502142306. It is not the latest evaluator version

Comment: Update both to latest versions - should take care of all known bugs and inconsistencies. What's your rationale of using outdated software (here, one and three years old versions) anyway?

Comment: There is none, I will push to promote our openscoring server + use the same JPMML classifier in both. Thank you.